# Cannot change brightness of my laptop

Tags: ati, dell, brightness

My laptop is a DELL 3521 with dual graphic cards, which usually cause some problems, and I have switched off the AMD Radeon card.

Now, when I want to turn the brightness down by dragging the brightness bar in the "Brightness and lock settings" and I close the window, nothing changes, and when I open "Brightness and Lock Settings" again, the brightness bar turn back to its previous state!

So, is it something is the system or I did some kind of mistake?

Answer (score 1):

**Try it once.. It has solved all problems about brightness! Including mine!!**

- Open terminal ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> ) and type:

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
  ```

  You will find this line in the new opened window: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
- Change it to:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
  ```
- Save and close the window and type this in the terminal:

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- Restart your system..